# create array using loop and input arithmetic progression value using loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, math

I'm noob in PHP programming and for my surprise I found it difficult to create an array using loop and to input in it values using arithmetic progression with +4 difference.I spent over an hour and tried a lot of code,searched so many examples.Below is my code that work(maybe) but not properly.

```
   <?php
 $array = [];
for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
 for($i=0;$i<100;$i+=4){
 $array[] = $i;
 }
 break;
}
var_dump($array);
?>
```

I must have no more than 10(0-9 key) values,but because of $i the loop continues to 96 up to 24 keys.Maybe it's stupid question but I've totally blocked.

Comment: So what you're looking for is just a 10 element list of `0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ...`, eh?

Comment: yes,in 10 keys(0-9) it must finish with 36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
<?php
$array = [];
for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
   $array[] = $x*4;
}
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Or maybe simpler

```
$array = range(0,36,4);
```

Doc for range : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.range.php

Comment: That helped me!But I prefer the first one because it sets how long array I want while the second is about values in the array.

Comment: For the 2nd solution, just in case, I think that `$array = range(0,$x*4,4)` where $x is number of values of your array is also possible. Nice to see that it resolves your problem. Cya! :)

Answer (score 1):

Then perhaps you have been overthinking this. You just need one loop, and can simply scale your key by `4`:

```
foreach (range(0, 10) as $x) {
    $array[] = 4 * $x;
}
```

Which will just add `0` for key `0`, and `4` for key `1`, and so on.

Note that for larger ranges, you should keep the classic [`for`](http://php.net/for) of course. It's more readable/obvious for math thingys anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this:- 

    for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
        $array[$x] = $x * 4;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
```

I think you must read basic of array here is a link that is useful for you [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)